# How to set html elements width to resize upon browser window resize?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm using Bootstrap and I'm struggling to ensure that the site is responsive to different screen sizes, i.e. when I resize my browser window, some of the elements do not resize accordingly. Similarly, when I select the iPhone display in the javascript console, it doesn't fit properly either.

Here's what I see when I halve the width my browser window:
[screen_view_small width window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3k5uO.png)

Here's what I'd like to see when I halve the width my browser window:
[screen_view_expected after resize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMwhH.png)

How can I fix this so that the width of the the elements adjust properly when the window is resized? It does work for my header, but not for the other elements: *col-md-10, containers and chart*. Height should stay constant, but width has to be responsive. Chart is done in Highcharts, no width or height values are passed in highchart.

My **html** file is set up as follows:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>    
    <head>
        <title>my title here</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <!-- Our Custom CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/style_charts_black.css">
        <script src="/static/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/static/Highcharts-5.0.14/code/highcharts.js"></script>
        <script src="/static/Highcharts-5.0.14/code/modules/exporting.js"></script>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        </head>

    <body>

    <div class="header-container">
        <header>
            ...
        </header>
    </div>

    <div class="container-fluid content-container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
            ...
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-10">
            ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

My custom **css** file is set up as follows:

```
body {
    position: relative;
    font-family: 'GothamBook', sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:300;
    height: 1100px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.content-container {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 65px 0 0;
    width: 100% !important;
    min-width: 768px;
    overflow: hidden !important;
}

.row {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden !important;
    position: relative;
    width: 99%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 13px;
}

.col-md-2 {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 250px;
    max-width: 250px;
    bottom: 20px;
}

.col-md-10 {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 255px;
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
    bottom: 20px;
}

.chart {
    position: absolute;
    width: 98%;
    height: 92%;
    margin-top: 35px;
}

.header-container{
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    height:65px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 11px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:101;
    min-width: 768px;
}

.header-container header{
    float:left;
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: since you are using bootstrap you don't need to redefine the rules for the grid and the columns like you've done with col-md-2 and col-md-10

Comment: @DanieleFois Are you suggesting that I should remove all the height and width arguments from the css file for col-md-2 and col-md-10?

Comment: yes, it's better you don't redefine width, height, margin and padding for those classes.

Comment: @DanieleFois I've tried that, but it doesn't fix the issue. I've removed entirely all .col-md-2 and .col-md-10 from the css file, but when I resize the browser window col-md-10 still doesn't resize ...

Answer (score 2):

Dude you are using bootstrap, try their grid classes, `col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12` .

Have a look at this https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid

> **Grid system**
>
> Bootstrap includes a responsive, mobile first fluid grid system that appropriately scales up to 12 columns as the device or viewport size increases. It includes predefined classes for easy layout options, as well as powerful mixins for generating more semantic layouts.
>
> ```
>              | Extra small devices Phones (<768px)| Small devices Tablets (≥768px)  |Medium devices Desktops (≥992px)   |Large devices Desktops (≥1200px) 
> __________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
>  Class prefix|   .col-xs-                         |       .col-sm-                  |       .col-md-                    |        .col-lg-
> __________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
> ```

Comment: I've had a look at this link before, but I'm not sure how to handle the mixing of grids. In the html, should I change the class to <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"> and then in the css file create rules for:
    .col-md-2 .col-sm-6 .col-xs-12 { 
        width: ...
        height:...
    }

Comment: @Joss no need to creat rules, the class are pre defined and there css too, for example col-xs-12 means `col-xs` = for mobile devices which uses css `Phones (<768px)` and `col-xs-12` means full width

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in my example I removed all the css references to width and height you had in your code... and now it works...

Give a bounce to this:

[Bootstrap Getting Started](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/%20%22Bootstrap%20Getting%20started)

**EDIT**
I also changed the class to `container` so you can achieve what you were looking for...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <!-- Our Custom CSS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
      * {outline: 1px solid red}
      body {
        font-family: 'GothamBook', sans-serif;
        font-size:12px;
        font-weight:300;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .chart {
        position: absolute;
        width: 98%;
        height: 92%;
        margin-top: 35px;
    }

    .header-container{
        height:65px;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 11px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
        top:0;
        left:0;
        z-index:101;
        min-width: 768px;
    }

</style>
</head>

<body>
 <div class="container">
    <header>
        ...
    </header>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Awesome - that fixed it indeed. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You have to add

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

at top of the page